# Override WP Login form HTML from wp_includes (general-template.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm wondering how can I edit the HTML for my WP Login Form. As I'm using WP for global login in the site I need to customize it for clients. The issue is that code I need to change is in a core folder. Most concretely at ./wp_includes/general-template.php

```
function wp_login_form( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'echo'           => true,
        // Default 'redirect' value takes the user back to the request URI.
        'redirect'       => ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
        'form_id'        => 'loginform',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username or Email Address' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
        'id_username'    => 'user_login',
        'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
        'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
        'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
        'remember'       => true,
        'value_username' => '',
        // Set 'value_remember' to true to default the "Remember me" checkbox to checked.
        'value_remember' => false,
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, apply_filters( 'login_form_defaults', $defaults ) );

    $login_form_top = apply_filters( 'login_form_top', '', $args );

    $login_form_bottom = apply_filters( 'login_form_bottom', '', $args );

    /**
    * This is the code I would like to edit
    */

    $form =
        sprintf(
            '<form name="%1$s" id="%1$s" action="%2$s" method="post">',
            esc_attr( $args['form_id'] ),
            esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) )
        ) .
        $login_form_top .
        sprintf(
            '<p class="login-username">
                <label for="%1$s">%2$s</label>
                <input type="text" name="log" id="%1$s" autocomplete="username" class="input" value="%3$s" size="20" />
            </p>',
            esc_attr( $args['id_username'] ),
            esc_html( $args['label_username'] ),
            esc_attr( $args['value_username'] )
        ) .
        sprintf(
            '<p class="login-password">
                <label for="%1$s">%2$s</label>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" id="%1$s" autocomplete="current-password" spellcheck="false" class="input" value="" size="20" />
            </p>',
            esc_attr( $args['id_password'] ),
            esc_html( $args['label_password'] )
        ) .
        $login_form_middle .
        ( $args['remember'] ?
            sprintf(
                '<p class="login-remember"><label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="%1$s" value="forever"%2$s /> %3$s</label></p>',
                esc_attr( $args['id_remember'] ),
                ( $args['value_remember'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '' ),
                esc_html( $args['label_remember'] )
            ) : ''
        ) .
        sprintf(
            '<p class="login-submit">
                <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="%1$s" class="button button-primary" value="%2$s" />
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="%3$s" />
            </p>',
            esc_attr( $args['id_submit'] ),
            esc_attr( $args['label_log_in'] ),
            esc_url( $args['redirect'] )
        ) .
        $login_form_bottom .
        '</form>';

    if ( $args['echo'] ) {
        echo $form;
    } else {
        return $form;
    }
}
```

Then, the login form is generated from a plugin with the wp_login_form() function:

```
function pmpro_login_form( $args = array() ) {
    add_filter( 'login_form_top', 'pmpro_login_form_hidden_field' );
    wp_login_form( $args );
    remove_filter( 'login_form_top', 'pmpro_login_form_hidden_field' );
}
```

First approach was edit the appearence of the form with CSS and JS. However I could get more effiency by editing the HTML.

Secondly, I can obviously edit the source core in wp_includes, but I don't think this is a valid approach. Besides, further updates will reset the content. So, main question is whcih would be the best approach to override the default $form constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a "better" way to edit the native wp-login form other than with hooks/filters and CSS.

I believe it would be better to consider creating a custom login form from scratch and then either:

- Display the custom login form on a different page
- Replace the wp-login template with your custom login form using the
  [template_include](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) filter
- Redirect from wp-login to your template using the [login_init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_init/)
  hook (if you also want to replace `/wp-login`)

There's also a topic on the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form) about this.